# Could not launch "MyApplication" launching failed:process launch failed:timed out waiting for app to launch?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am working on one universal application, when i run this application it shows error like "Could not launch "MyApplication" launching failed:process launch failed:timed out waiting for app to launch?"
  I have already tried :

- closing and reopening the Xcode
- deleted the app from device and tried rerun
- restarted the device
- reviewed build settings for checking correct code signing identities
- finally restarted the my Mac System

but nothing helped.

Comment: The message means that you app is taking to long to start, make sure you are not doing any unnecessary tasks in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. You should always return for this method as fast a possible.

Comment: Sometimes, I had to clean the cache of xcode.Try to see this post for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4

Comment: How to resolve this one?can you please tell me

Comment: iam already clean the all catche files in xcode but it s not work

Comment: @rckoenes,how to solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure that don't block or prolong the startup of you app. With code we will never be able to help you.

Comment: Reset the simulator. If u r using the device, remove ur account and add it again

Comment: Any one can guide me to solve this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. You should not do any time taking tasks in that method.